# Error after error in booting and in recovery mood

Tags: recovery-mode, installation, system-error

My tablet brand is ASUS and its android's version is 5.0.1. It shows many error  likes `Unfortunately com.android.setings has stopped`, `Unfortunately UI has stopped`, `Unfortunately Launcher has stopped` frequently. Sometimes when I restart it, it doesn't show my desktop. Also its reset to factory doesn't works properly (it just reset the time of tablet).

I have cleared the cache and data of `setting` but errors persists.

So I decided to `recover` my android. After holding power button and + volume, I chose `recover` option and it got to the recovery page. after 5-7 seconds the error appeared with death android icon and just the word "error" as its caption.

> How to recover my android? what files I need? What is the adb?

Please note that my (android of) tablet is not longer supported by ASUS Inc. Also I have reset my android to factory setting 1 month ago successfully.

Comment: Can you share the exact model of your tablet and some more details about it. If it's rooter or not?

Comment: No it is not rooter. My tablet model number: K019 (2014).

Comment: In my opinion an update of Google Play Services cause an error on your tablet and since everything is tied to that it's keep crashing.

Answer (score 0):

I have downloaded My tablet driver from [ASUS website](https://www.asus.com/support/Download-Center/) and then the following `ADB` command in boot menu resolved the problem completely. (notice that it removes user data I think!)

```
adb sideload <filename>
```